# aws php sdk - elastic transcoder (Preset ARN is invalid: relative id null does not conform to the ARN specification)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm using the AWS PHP SDK. (with laravel)
I am trying to convert a video file between s3 buckets.

```
$transcoder = App::make('aws')->get('ElasticTranscoder');
//$transcoder->setRegion('us-west-2');

// add to queue
$result = $transcoder->createJob(array(
  'PipelineId' => '1111111111111-l1zkmo',
  'Input' => array(
    'Key' => $key
  ),
  'Output' => array(
    'Key' => $output_key              
  ),
));
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Preset ARN is invalid: relative id null does not conform to the ARN specification
```

If I try, for example to listPipelines it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the preset id was not included in the Output:

```
$result = $transcoder->createJob(array(
  'PipelineId' => '1111111111-5wtswy',
  'Input' => array(
    'Key' => $key
  ),
  'Output' => array(
    'Key' => $output_key,
    'PresetId' => '1351620000001-100070'          
  ),
));
```